# How to generate dynamic tiles

Tags: tiles

I was studying the [Trulia crime map](http://www.trulia.com/local/los-angeles-ca) and found that they were generating dynamic tiles with color block based on crime count. I am a newbie to mapping world and found how to generate static tiles, serve them, cache them etc. I am not able to understand how to generate dynamic tiles based on crime count.

On the data side, i have the latitude and longitude about where the crime happened. Is it possible to generate dynamic polygon tiles with this data ?

Comment: Can you tell us what software you are using?